# Flask SQLalchemy code doesn’t ‘see’ database entries after rerun the code

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I created a small Database with one table and filled it with data. It worked perfectly. However, after I exited the VSCode and entered it again, the code recognizes the DB and makes requests, but gets an empty list as a result (as if it doesn’t ‘see’ DB entries). The DB is full of data; I can see it in DB browser. Moreover, a code in another file which imports the DBmodel from the first one successfully gets proper data. What might be wrong with the first file?
The first file (app.py):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///myDB.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False # I tried also True

with app.app_context():
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)

    class Recipy(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True) 
        title = db.Column(db.String(100), index = True, unique = True) 
        …
    db.create_all()
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    rows=Recipy.query.all()
    print(rows) # it is just to have results on terminal; results are an empty list [] both here and on the html-page
    return render_template("home.html", rows=rows, search_form=search_form)
…
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

>>> []
```

the second file which successfully gets the data:

```
from app import app, db, Recipy
with app.app_context():
    a=Recipy.query.get(2)
    rows=Recipy.query.order_by(Recipy.title).all()
    print(a, rows)

>>> <Recipy 2> [<Recipy 1>, <Recipy 2>, …]
```

Both files are in the same folder. Both times I run it within the same venv.
I will be very grateful for a hint.

I tried app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
I also tried similar pieces of code created in another folder with another Database (which included two tables), but the results were the same.

Updated:
According a comment, I added app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = "debug".
The terminal output is as follows:
For the first function:

```
023-01-10 17:23:27,458 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Created new connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000268DFA0DB40>
2023-01-10 17:23:27,459 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000268DFA0DB40> checked out from pool
2023-01-10 17:23:27,460 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-10 17:23:27,467 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT recipy.id AS recipy_id, recipy.title AS recipy_title, recipy.author AS recipy_author, recipy.ingredients AS recipy_ingredients, recipy.instructions AS recipy_instructions     
FROM recipy
2023-01-10 17:23:27,468 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00207s] ()
2023-01-10 17:23:27,470 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('recipy_id', 'recipy_title', 'recipy_author', 'recipy_ingredients', 'recipy_instructions')
[]
2023-01-10 17:23:27,491 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2023-01-10 17:23:27,494 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000268DFA0DB40> being returned to pool
2023-01-10 17:23:27,501 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000268DFA0DB40> rollback-on-return
2023-01-10 17:23:27,504 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000268DFA0DB40>
```

For the function that does return results:

```
2023-01-10 18:15:46,205 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Created new connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9B40>
2023-01-10 18:15:46,205 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9B40> checked out from pool
2023-01-10 18:15:46,216 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,217 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA main.table_info("recipy")
2023-01-10 18:15:46,218 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2023-01-10 18:15:46,219 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('cid', 'name', 'type', 'notnull', 'dflt_value', 'pk')     
2023-01-10 18:15:46,220 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (0, 'id', 'INTEGER', 1, None, 1)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,220 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (1, 'title', 'VARCHAR(100)', 0, None, 0)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,221 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (2, 'author', 'VARCHAR(40)', 0, None, 0)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,222 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (3, 'ingredients', 'VARCHAR(500)', 0, None, 0)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,223 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (4, 'instructions', 'VARCHAR(4000)', 0, None, 0)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,224 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-01-10 18:15:46,226 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9B40> being returned to pool
2023-01-10 18:15:46,227 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9B40> rollback-on-return
2023-01-10 18:15:46,230 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9B40>
2023-01-10 18:15:46,239 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Created new connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9940>
2023-01-10 18:15:46,240 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9940> checked out from pool
2023-01-10 18:15:46,241 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,245 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT recipy.id AS recipy_id, recipy.title AS recipy_title, recipy.author AS recipy_author, recipy.ingredients AS recipy_ingredients, recipy.instructions AS recipy_instructions     
FROM recipy
WHERE recipy.id = ?
2023-01-10 18:15:46,246 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00101s] (2,)
2023-01-10 18:15:46,248 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('recipy_id', 'recipy_title', 'recipy_author', 'recipy_ingredients', 'recipy_instructions')
2023-01-10 18:15:46,249 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (2, 'Omelet', 'Serge', '2 eggs,\nmilk, \r\nolive oil', 'Mix it and fry on the pan')
2023-01-10 18:15:46,253 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT recipy.id AS recipy_id, recipy.title AS recipy_title, recipy.author AS recipy_author, recipy.ingredients AS recipy_ingredients, recipy.instructions AS recipy_instructions     
FROM recipy ORDER BY recipy.title
2023-01-10 18:15:46,254 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00130s] ()
2023-01-10 18:15:46,255 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('recipy_id', 'recipy_title', 'recipy_author', 'recipy_ingredients', 'recipy_instructions')
2023-01-10 18:15:46,256 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (1, 'Baked apple', 'Serge', 'apple', 'Just bake it')       
2023-01-10 18:15:46,256 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row (2, 'Omelet', 'Serge', '2 eggs,\nmilk, \r\nolive oil', 'Mix it and fry on the pan')
… (10 more similar rows with the content)
<Recipy 2> [<Recipy 1>, <Recipy 2>, <Recipy 4>, <Recipy 10>, <Recipy 12>, <Recipy 14>, <Recipy 13>, <Recipy 9>, <Recipy 8>, <Recipy 7>, <Recipy 5>]
2023-01-10 18:15:46,268 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
2023-01-10 18:15:46,269 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9940> being returned to pool
2023-01-10 18:15:46,269 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9940> rollback-on-return
2023-01-10 18:15:46,270 DEBUG sqlalchemy.pool.impl.NullPool Closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x00000286178E9940>
```

Comment: Please set `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_ECHO"] = "debug"` and [edit] your question to add the terminal output from triggering your route.

Comment: Yes, please, I did it.

Comment: Can you do the same for the function that does return results ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not doing it at once.

Comment: You wrote that the dbURI is `'sqlite:///myDB.db'`, which depends on `os.getcwd()`. Are you _sure_ the file being used by the webapp is identical to the one where an interactive .query.get(2) succeeds? Are you logging CWD? Maybe log the size of that file, then INSERT a hundred rows and re-examine the size?

Comment: @J_H You are right. My mistake was that when running the code second time I was in another directory (according the VSCode’s command line), so a new myDB.db was created in another location. (I can’t figure out how my second file (which imported the db from the first one) still requested the right database.) But anyway, the problem is solved. Thank you very much for your answer and your patience. Should I somehow note that the problem is solved, or describe a way of solving, or delete the original thread? I am a new to the community, so I don’t know what the proper way to do it here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that the dbURI is 'sqlite:///myDB.db', which depends on os.getcwd(), current working directory.

Ensure that CWD is always the same,
or use an absolute pathname.